# Separate Sections work correctly however when combined a crash is caused

Tags: c

The program works when the edit is alone and it also works when the read is alone :

```
    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to edit:\n");
    gets(file_name); //file_name = input

    file = fopen(file_name,"w"); // write mode

   if( file == NULL ) //If file couldn't be opened
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

    printf("Enter name: \n"); scanf("%s",name1);
    printf("Enter second name if applicable: \n"); scanf("%s",name2);
    printf("Enter grade: \n"); scanf("%s",grade);
    fprintf(file, "%s%s%s\t%s%s%s", name1, " ", name2, "=", " ", grade);
    fclose(file);
    printf("File write was successful\n");
```

And

```
   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see:\n");
   gets(file_name); //file_name = input

   file = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

   if( file == NULL ) //If file couldn't be opened
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are:\n", file_name);

    while( ( character = fgetc(file) ) != EOF /*EOF = End Of File*/)
        printf("%c",character); //print c (character)

   fclose(file); //remove the file from RAM
```

However when they are put together with an if the program crashes as soon as 1 or 2 is inputted into the first section:

```
 printf("Edit or Read file? (1 for edit, 2 or read)\n"); scanf("%s",RW);
```

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char character, file_name[25];
    int RW;
    const char *quit;
    FILE *file; //"file" stores file stream
    char data [100000];
    char name1 [100000];
    char name2 [100000];
    char grade [100000];

    printf("Edit or Read file? (1 for edit, 2 or read)\n"); scanf("%s",RW);

    if (RW == 1)
    {
       printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see:\n");
       gets(file_name); //file_name = input

       file = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

       if( file == NULL ) //If file couldn't be opened
       {
          perror("Error while opening the file!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("The contents of %s file are:\n", file_name);

        while( ( character = fgetc(file) ) != EOF /*EOF = End Of File*/)
            printf("%c",character); //print c (character)

       fclose(file); //remove the file from RAM
    } else if ( RW == 2) {

        printf("Enter the name of file you wish to edit:\n");
        gets(file_name); //file_name = input

        file = fopen(file_name,"w"); // write mode

       if( file == NULL ) //If file couldn't be opened
       {
          perror("Error while opening the file!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

        printf("Enter name: \n"); scanf("%s",name1);
        printf("Enter second name if applicable: \n"); scanf("%s",name2);
        printf("Enter grade: \n"); scanf("%s",grade);
        fprintf(file, "%s%s%s\t%s%s%s", name1, " ", name2, "=", " ", grade);
        fclose(file);
        printf("File write was successful\n");
    }

    printf(" \n");
    printf("Close window?\n"); scanf("%s",quit);
    if (quit == "y")
    {
        printf("Bye!\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s",RW);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &RW);`

Comment: 2) `const char *quit;` --> `char quit;` ... `scanf("%s",quit); if(quit == "y")` --> `scanf(" %c", &quit); if(quit == 'y')`

Comment: Thanks! I believe that that has solved the problem, THUMBS UP!

Comment: First and foremost, the posted code is a long long ways from cleanly compiling.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.   (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.   For a start, there are a number of variables that are being used before being initialzied.

Comment: `gets()` is depreciated due to its' major problems, and is completely removed from the latest C standard.   Strongly suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans:  follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.   2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always use a max length modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid a buffer overflow, leading to a seg fault event.  3) successive calls with the '%s' format specifier will tend to fail, unless there is a leading space (to consume left over white space) in each of the format strings.

Comment: the program will exit regardless of the user response to the "close window" question,.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s",quit);` the variable `quit` is a pointer, not a char.  Suggest: `char quit;`  and `scanf(" %c", &quit);` and `if ('y' == quit )`   Note: always place the literal on the left so a keypunch error like: `('y' = guit )` will be caught by the compiler rather than you spending hours looking for that error.

Comment: this line: `fprintf(file, "%s%s%s\t%s%s%s", name1, " ", name2, "=", " ", grade);`  would be much better written as: `fprintf( file, "%s %s\t = %s", name1,  name2,  grade );`

Comment: The `if--else if` sequence needs clarifying,.  Suggest: switch( RW ) { case 1:   // read operations  break;  case 2: // write operations break;  default: printf( "invalid entry, program exiting\n" ); break;  }

Comment: the variable `character` is declared as a `char`, but the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int` AND EOF is an `int`   so the declaration should be: `int character;`

Comment: why are you declaring each of the char arrays: `data[]`, `name1[]`, `name2[]` and `grade[]` as each 10000 bytes long.?   Strongly suggest thinking about what your actually want the user to input and declaring the data appropriately and use appropriate format specifiers in the calls to `scanf()` for that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the posted program crashes because of this line:

```
scanf("%s",RW);
```

the variable `RW` is declared as an `int`.

The call to `scanf()` is expecting a pointer to an char array.

so the code is trying to tread `RW` as a pointer, and followed that pointer (which contains what ever trash was on the stack at the location of `RW`.  That is what is causing the crash.

Suggest writing the statement as:

```
scanf("%u",&RW);
```

Answer (score 0):

As BLUEPIXY said:

`scanf("%s",RW);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &RW);`

`const char *quit;` --> `char quit;` ... `scanf("%s",quit); if(quit == "y")` --> `scanf(" %c", &quit); if(quit == 'y')`

These changes meant that there were no problems with the variables.

Comment: All the comments have been extremely useful to me, thanks for the help and advice on further improvement.